# Why do I get "configure:error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH" when installing GCC on my Apache server?

Tags: apache, gcc, compiler-construction, path

I'm attempting to install GCC 4.5.1 on my Apache server, but it says there is no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH. Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated.

When I use `echo $PATH` it prints:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/:/var/lib/:/usr/share/

These are the commands I used to configure GCC:
`sudo mkdir /usr/bin/gcc/`
`cd /usr/bin/gcc/`
`sudo /gcc-4.5.1/configure`

These are the results of those commands:

> checking build system type...
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
>  checking
>   host system type...
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>  checking
>   target system type...
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>  checking
>   for a BSD-compatible install...
>   /usr/bin/install -c
>  checking
>   whether ln works... yes
>  checking
>   whether ln -s works... yes
>   checking for a sed that does not
>   truncate output... /bin/sed
>   checking for gawk... no
>  checking
>   for mawk... mawk
>  checking for
>   gcc... no
>  checking for cc...
>   no
>  checking for cl.exe... no
>   configure: error: in
>   '/usr/bin/gcc:'`
>  configure: error:
>   no acceptable C compiler found in
>   $PATH
>  See 'config.log' for more
>   details.

The file config.log contains:

> This file contains any messages
>   produced by compilers while running
>   configure, to aid debugging if
>   configure makes a mistake.
>
> It was created by configure, which was
>   generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64. 
>   Invocation command line was
>
> $ /gcc-4.5.1/configure
>
> ### ---------
>
> ### Platform.
>
> ### ---------
>
> hostname = wordpress-juicesite uname
>   -m = x86_64 uname -r = 2.6.31-302-rs uname -s = Linux uname -v = #7 SMP Thu
>   Oct 29 22:57:03 UTC 2009
>
> /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown /bin/uname
>   -X     = unknown
>
> /bin/arch              = unknown
>   /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
>   /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
>   /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
>   /bin/machine           = unknown
>   /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
>   /bin/universe          = unknown
>
> PATH: /usr/local/sbin PATH:
>   /usr/local/bin PATH: /usr/sbin PATH:
>   /usr/bin PATH: /sbin PATH: /bin PATH:
>   /usr/X11R6/bin
>
> ### -----------
>
> ### Core tests.
>
> ### -----------
>
> configure:2429: checking build system
>   type configure:2443: result:
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   configure:2490: checking host system
>   type configure:2503: result:
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   configure:2523: checking target system
>   type configure:2536: result:
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   configure:2590: checking for a
>   BSD-compatible install configure:2658:
>   result: /usr/bin/install -c
>   configure:2669: checking whether ln
>   works configure:2691: result: yes
>   configure:2695: checking whether ln -s
>   works configure:2699: result: yes
>   configure:2706: checking for a sed
>   that does not truncate output
>   configure:2770: result: /bin/sed
>   configure:2779: checking for gawk
>   configure:2809: result: no
>   configure:2779: checking for mawk
>   configure:2795: found /usr/bin/mawk
>   configure:2806: result: mawk
>   configure:4039: checking for gcc
>   configure:4069: result: no
>   configure:4132: checking for cc
>   configure:4179: result: no
>   configure:4235: checking for cl.exe
>   configure:4265: result: no
>   configure:4289: error: in
>   `/usr/bin/gcc': configure:4292: error:
>   no acceptable C compiler found in
>   $PATH See`config.log' for more
>   details.
>
> ### ----------------
>
> ### Cache variables.
>
> ### ----------------
>
> ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_AR_set= ac_cv_env_AR_value=
>   ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_AS_set= ac_cv_env_AS_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CC_set= ac_cv_env_CC_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
>   ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
>   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
>   ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
>   ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
>   ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
>   ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_LD_set= ac_cv_env_LD_value=
>   ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
>   ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
>   ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
>   ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
>   ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_NM_set= ac_cv_env_NM_value=
>   ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
>   ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
>   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
>   ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
>   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
>   ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
>   ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
>   ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
>   ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
>   ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
>   ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
>   ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
>   ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
>   ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
>   ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
>   ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   ac_cv_path_SED=/bin/sed
>   ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install
>   -c' ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   acx_cv_prog_LN=ln
>
> ### -----------------
>
> ### Output variables.
>
> ### -----------------
>
> AR='' AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
>   AR_FOR_TARGET='' AS=''
>   AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)' AS_FOR_TARGET=''
>   AWK='mawk' BISON='' BUILD_CONFIG=''
>   CC='' CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
>   CC_FOR_TARGET='' CFLAGS=''
>   CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
>   CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
>   COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
>   COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
>   COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
>   CONFIGURE_GDB_TK='' CPP='' CPPFLAGS=''
>   CXX='' CXXFLAGS=''
>   CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
>   CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
>   CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
>   CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
>   DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
>   DEFS='' DLLTOOL=''
>   DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
>   DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET='' ECHO_C=''
>   ECHO_N='-n' ECHO_T='' EGREP=''
>   EXEEXT='' EXPECT=''
>   FLAGS_FOR_TARGET='' FLEX=''
>   GCC_FOR_TARGET='' GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
>   GCJ_FOR_BUILD='$(GCJ)'
>   GCJ_FOR_TARGET='' GDB_TK=''
>   GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
>   GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET='' GNATBIND=''
>   GNATMAKE='' GREP=''
>   INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
>   INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
>   INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
>   INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}' LD=''
>   LDFLAGS='' LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
>   LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)' LD_FOR_TARGET=''
>   LEX='' LIBOBJS='' LIBS='' LIPO=''
>   LIPO_FOR_TARGET='' LN='ln' LN_S='ln
>   -s' LTLIBOBJS='' M4='' MAINT='' MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
>   MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='' MAKEINFO=''
>   NM='' NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
>   NM_FOR_TARGET='' OBJCOPY='' OBJDUMP=''
>   OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET='' OBJEXT=''
>   PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='' PACKAGE_NAME=''
>   PACKAGE_STRING='' PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
>   PACKAGE_URL='' PACKAGE_VERSION=''
>   PATH_SEPARATOR=':' RANLIB=''
>   RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
>   RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
>   RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET='' RPATH_ENVVAR=''
>   RUNTEST='' SED='/bin/sed'
>   SHELL='/bin/bash' STRIP=''
>   STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
>   SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
>   TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='/gcc-4.5.1/configure'
>   WINDMC='' WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
>   WINDMC_FOR_TARGET='' WINDRES=''
>   WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
>   WINDRES_FOR_TARGET='' YACC=''
>   ac_ct_CC='' ac_ct_CXX=''
>   bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
>   build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   build_alias='' build_configargs=''
>   build_configdirs='build-libiberty
>   build-texinfo build-byacc build-flex
>   build-bison build-m4
>   build-fixincludes' build_cpu='x86_64'
>   build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   build_noncanonical='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   build_os='linux-gnu'
>   build_subdir='build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   build_tooldir=''
>   build_vendor='unknown' clooginc=''
>   clooglibs='' compare_exclusions=''
>   config_shell='/bin/bash'
>   configdirs='intl mmalloc libiberty
>   opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl
>   libgui zlib libcpp libdecnumber gmp
>   mpfr mpc ppl cloog libelf libiconv
>   texinfo byacc flex bison binutils gas
>   ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb
>   make patch prms send-pr gprof etc
>   expect dejagnu ash bash bzip2 m4
>   autoconf automake libtool diff rcs
>   fileutils shellutils time textutils
>   wdiff find uudecode hello tar gzip
>   indent recode release sed utils guile
>   perl gawk findutils gettext zip
>   fastjar gnattools'
>   datadir='${datarootdir}'
>   datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
>   do_compare=''
>   docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
>   dvidir='${docdir}' exec_prefix='NONE'
>   extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
>   extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
>   extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
>   extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
>   gmpinc='' gmplibs=''
>   host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   host_alias='' host_configargs=''
>   host_cpu='x86_64'
>   host_noncanonical='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   host_os='linux-gnu' host_subdir='.'
>   host_vendor='unknown'
>   htmldir='${docdir}'
>   includedir='${prefix}/include'
>   infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
>   libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
>   libelfinc='' libelflibs=''
>   libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
>   localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
>   localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
>   mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
>   oldincludedir='/usr/include'
>   pdfdir='${docdir}'
>   poststage1_ldflags=''
>   poststage1_libs='' pplinc=''
>   ppllibs='' prefix='NONE'
>   program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
>   psdir='${docdir}'
>   sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
>   sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
>   stage1_cflags='' stage1_checking=''
>   stage1_languages='' stage1_ldflags=''
>   stage1_libs='' stage2_werror_flag=''
>   sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
>   target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   target_alias='' target_configargs=''
>   target_configdirs='target-libgcc
>   target-libiberty target-libgloss
>   target-newlib target-libgomp
>   target-libstdc++-v3 target-libmudflap
>   target-libssp target-libgfortran
>   target-boehm-gc target-libffi
>   target-zlib target-qthreads
>   target-libjava target-libobjc
>   target-libada target-examples
>   target-groff target-gperf target-rda'
>   target_cpu='x86_64'
>   target_noncanonical='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   target_os='linux-gnu'
>   target_subdir='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>   target_vendor='unknown' tooldir=''
>
> ### -------------------
>
> ### File substitutions.
>
> ### -------------------
>
> alphaieee_frag=''
>   host_makefile_frag='/dev/null'
>   ospace_frag=''
>   serialization_dependencies=''
>   target_makefile_frag=''
>
> ### -----------
>
> ### confdefs.h.
>
> ### -----------
>
> /* confdefs.h */
>
> ## define PACKAGE_NAME ""
>
> ## define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
>
> ## define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
>
> ## define PACKAGE_STRING ""
>
> ## define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
>
> ## define PACKAGE_URL ""
>
> configure: exit 1

Comment: Side note: It looks rather strange that you create a `/usr/bin/gcc` directory. Are you sure you want to create a directory there? Also, it would most probably be easier to install a binary package than to compile it from source. Preferably use the systems package management software to do it.

Comment: Thanks sth! Where would you say is a better place to create the gcc directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to build gcc from source ? Then you need a compiler to compile it.. (that's a Catch 22...).

Can't you install a binary package with the compiler already compiled ?

Comment: Thank you so much, Andre and sth!

Comment: If you tell use which type of Linux distribution you are using (ubuntu, CentOS etc.) people might be able to tell you the command to install a pre-compiled version of gcc.

(I assume you're using Linux by looking at the output of uname -s above)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. That would be super helpful!

Comment: From the command line, try

 sudo apt-get install gcc . Although I think the directory /usr/bin/gcc/ which you seem to have made initially will be in the way, so you probably have to rename the directory before installing gcc.